# Relationship between eigenvectors of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have matrix  $A \in R^{2n \text{x} 2n} $ given by $X^{-1} diag(W - iY, W + iY) X$
and matrix $B \in C^{n \text{x} n}$ and $B = W + iY$.

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$. How can I relate $v$ to some eigenvector of $B$?

Comment: What do you understand here by $diag(W - iY, W + iY)$?

Comment: Are $W, Y$ numbers, so that $\text{diag}(W - iY, W + iY)$ is $2 \times 2$, or is $\text{diag}(W - iY, W + iY)$ a block diagonal matrix?  Cheers!

Comment: @Robert They are block matrices.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since, $X$ is invertible, $\exists u\in C^n$ such that $Xu=[0\quad v^T]^T$ where $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ and $0\in C^n$. Then, it easily follows that $Au=\lambda u$ where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $B$ corresponding to $v$. So, the eigenspace of $B$ is a subspace of the eigenspace of $A$. Similarly you can show that the other set of $n$ eigenvectors of $A$ belong to the eigenspace of $W-iY$, so that the eigenspace of $A$ is the sum of the eigenspaces of $W+iY$ and $W-iY$.

In fact this directly follows from the fact that $\det(A-\lambda I_{2n})=\det(W+iY-\lambda I_n)\det(W-iY-\lambda I_n)$